# How to Concatenate string with list in python within for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i've some problem to join the string with my variable and some string within the list, here's the example:

i have some list :

```
my_list = ['about.html', 'contact.html', 'home.html']
```

and some var:

```
my_var = 'localhost:8000/'
```

i want to join the var with the list so i have something like:

```
my_finished_list = ['localhost:8000/about.html', 'localhost:8000/contact.html', 'localhost:8000/home.html']
```

how would you concatenate string and those list together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
my_finished_list = [my_var+list_item for list_item in my_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code.

```
my_list = ['about.html', 'contact.html', 'home.html']
my_var = 'localhost:8000/'
my_finished_list=[]
for x in my_list:
    my_finished_list.append(my_var+x)
print(my_finished_list)
```

Result:

```
['localhost:8000/about.html', 'localhost:8000/contact.html', 'localhost:8000/home.html']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
my_list = ['about.html', 'contact.html', 'home.html']
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = 'localhost:8000/' + my_list[i]
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in my_list:
    my_finished_list.append(my_var + item)
```

there is a more pythonic way but if u want it in a simple for loop this should seal the deal.